# Regarding Data Entry extensibility

Tags: wallets, data, attachments

Noticed this in stellar-core:

```
/* DataEntry
Data can be attached to accounts.
*/

struct DataEntry

{
    AccountID accountID; // account this data belongs to
    string64 dataName;
    DataValue dataValue;

// reserved for future use
  union switch (int v)
  {
  case 0:
    void;
  }
  ext;
};
```

1) What are the architecural considerations here / how else may be extended?
2) As more applications start use data entries / attachments, do you envision wallets still being the main UI layer for this data, or is this moreso geared towards specifized account viewers in custom applications?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been pushing the limits of data fields storing code and images, definitely a special viewer is required and in the case of code a virtual machine to run them.

Take a look here, this is code stored on a Stellar account in the data field:

http://myplaynet.herokuapp.com/stellar/apps